# Which definition of 'bide' in 'bide time'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> [bide one's time](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bide-one%27s-time) = Wait quietly for a good opportunity to do something [(example)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stalking_horse)

1. How do you determine/deduce the apt meaning / definition (de novo) ? Please explain the steps, thought processes; I’d like to try to resolve this myself in the future?

2. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bide+time does contain '2a.  To wait; tarry.' But is 'wait' the right choice?

3. What about Definition 2b? 'To stay in time' makes sense?

4. Or definition 1? 'To remain' in time makes sense also?

Comment: In 2) you gave the definitions of "bide", not "bide your time" which is an idiom (def. To wait for further developments.)

Comment: The word *bide* has no Modern English definition.  The meaning is now associated with the entire phrase *bide (one)'s time*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In re: your questions **`2`** through **`4`**, first note that "*biding one's time*" is an idiom, and there is [no guarantee the meaning of an idiom can be deduced from its component words](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/idiom), and in general no good way to identify an idiom from its form (i.e. to even know you're dealing with an idiom in the first place).

That said, from [the very link you provided](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bide-one%27s-time):

[image: definition of "bide" and "bide one's time"]

In re: your question **`1`**:

> 1. How do you determine/deduce the apt meaning / definition (de novo)?

In the general case:

1. context (*reasoning*)
2. experience  (*pattern matching*)
3. and a good dictionary (*evidence*)

Sorry, there's no magic shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that most native English speakers learn a dictionary definition of "bide" before understanding "bide one's time".  First, many native English speakers never learn the idiom "bide one's time".  Second, I expect that (of the native English speakers who do learn the idiom) most learned it by reading something like this:

> He was biding his time, waiting for his ship to come in.

or:

> Jack was patient.  Where other men would get frustrated and give up, he bided his time.

or by singing a hymn:

> [Abide with me](http://library.timelesstruths.org/music/Abide_with_Me/); fast falls the eventide;
>
> The darkness deepens; Lord, with me abide;
>
> When other helpers fail and comforts flee,
>
> Help of the helpless, oh, abide with me.

So I would expect many people to learn the meaning of "bide" from an implicit definition given near a usage of "bide one's time'.

Comment: @LePressentiment -- You may have noticed that the answers to many of your questions match implicit definitions given in your example quotations.

Comment: I expect **all** adult native speakers to understand "I'm just biding my time".

Comment: @snailboat -- That sounds like a good bar bet.  What resources are there for checking what fraction of native English speakers understand any particular idiom?

Comment: +1. Thank you. I'll try to dredge up the  'implicit definitions' but they easily elude my rudimentary English...

Comment: A much-quoted phrase from a famous movie, The Big Lebowski:   "The dude abides."  Abiding and biding have the connotation of patience.